# Swedish citizenship application - what happens if you stayed in another Nordic country ”in between”?

Tags: citizenship, sweden

I’ve applied for swedish citizenship some 26 months ago and no decision as of yet. 
I moved to Sweden in 2009, studied & worked until autumn 2013, then moved to Denmark for work until 2015. 
Then I moved back to sweden (again) in 2016 with another job and only this time I got a PR permit.

Soon after the PR, I’ve applied for the citizenship as stated above. Few weeks earlier my case officer contacted me asking about Denmark & requested to send “evidence” about my work in Denmark. Sent it and no words or decision yet.

Questions are:

1. Is my citizenship application invalid since I was in Denmark in between years?
2. Does it have ANY impact on my PR permit (e.g. revoked)?
3. Should I just be more patient?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say what country you're currently a citizen of, and the rules for citizens of Nordic countries, EU/EEA countries, and other countries are all a little different.

But according to the "Becoming a Swedish Citizen" Section on the [Migrationsverket web site](https://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/Becoming-a-Swedish-citizen/Citizenship-for-adults/Time-in-Sweden.html),

> If you have travelled abroad on, for example, short trips or holidays, this is of no importance for your period of habitual residence in Sweden. But if you have been abroad for more than six weeks in a year, the whole period you were outside Sweden is deducted from the period of habitual residence. If you move to another country and settle there your habitual residence is interrupted. You can start to count your habitual residence from the day you move back to Sweden again.

It doesn't appear to treat time in another Nordic country differently, just time outside of Sweden.